# How to align the text in a text view and label in iOS

Tags: ios, layout, xib

I am trying to make a little layout file where I have a label above a text view. Using constraints, both have the same padding left value. The text box seems to have padding by default. Can I do something to fix it or should I fiddle around with the values to find something that would be acceptable?

Here is a picture of the layout

[image: Layout]

Comment: Try yourTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;

Comment: Is this the only method? Is there a parameter that could be changed in the xib?

Comment: You can also select your textView, then go to the identity inspector and under the "User Defined Run Time Attributes" add a new key path of "textContainer.lineFragmentPadding", type is "Number" and value "0"

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

Super simple (Xcode 11.2, Swift 5):

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```